# spark partitionBy with partitioned column in json output

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

im reading below json in spark

```
{"bucket": "B01", "actionType": "A1", "preaction": "NULL", "postaction": "NULL"}
{"bucket": "B02", "actionType": "A2", "preaction": "NULL", "postaction": "NULL"}
{"bucket": "B03", "actionType": "A3", "preaction": "NULL", "postaction": "NULL"}

val df=spark.read.json("actions.json").toDF()
```

Now im writing the same to a json output as below

```
df.write. format("json"). mode("append"). partitionBy("bucket","actionType"). save("output.json")
```

and the output.json is as below

```
{"preaction":"NULL","postaction":"NULL"}
```

bucket,actionType columns are missing in the json output, i need partitionby columns as well in the output

Comment: Why do you want to include partition columns? They're part of the directory structure and so not included.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a workaround by creating duplicate columns to be used in `partitionBy` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(Seq(col("bucket").as("bucketCopy"), col("actionType").as("actionTypeCopy")) ++ df.columns.map(col): _*)
  .write.format("json").mode("append").partitionBy("bucketCopy","actionTypeCopy"). save("output.json")
```